# Read multiple .txt files in a single folder

Tags: python, list, text, glob

I want to read from multiple .txt file in a single folder, and read every line as a list.

[image]

[image]

This is my code, however it prints nothing.

```
import glob
import errno
path = '/Users/xccxken/PycharmProjects/untitled7/NNRelease/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                words = list()
                for word in line.split():
                    words.append(word)
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
    print(words)
```

I hope the resulting is two lists a and b

```
a=[class,company,family,..]
b=[size, size, size,...]
```

Another question is the print lists contains some empty lists, (I think it is because the original txt files has empty row) Please tell me how to remove these empty lists. Thanks!

In addition, I need to delete the lists that contain "#” thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think `files` may be empty.  Use an absolute path, or `os.chdir` into the directory

```
import glob
import errno
path = 'C:/Users/xccxken/PycharmProjects/untitled7/NNRelease/*.txt' #note C:
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line.split())
    except IOError as exc: #Not sure what error this is
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

To only print lines with data

```
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            split = line.split()
            if split:
                print(line.split())
```

Comment: Another question is the print lists contains some empty lists, (I think it is because the original txt files has empty row) Can you tell me how to remove these empty lists? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Thank you so much! And I have another question I just found that I need to delete the list that contain "#”， thank you very much for your time!

Comment: `#` as it's own element or things like `#5` ?

Comment: thanks! for example, i want to delete lists like ['#...'], ['#shortfall/shortage', '-', 'conflict', 'between', 'DESIRED/USED', 'amount', 'and', 'AVAILABLE/PRESENT', 'amount'], ['#attribute']

Comment: `if split and all('#' not in i for i in split)`

Comment: sir, can you tell me how to transfer it into two list a and b; a = [class, company, family,...], b=[size, size, size....]